# How can I work around pagination using chunk because of repeated errors being thrown?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I'm trying to paginate my json response in terms of multiples of 20 but for some reason, I'm getting `Error: Call to a member function chunk() on array`.

To clarify, `$results` has data in it and `$request->get('offset');` has a value.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?  I'm seeing examples when searching on SO where people are doing this on a collection but for some reason, it isn't working for me. How can I make this work?

**Note:** If I do `dd($results['num_results']);`, it displays `360`.  I feel like I need to use this some how but I'm not sure how.  I'm trying to achieve this in the most Laravel way possible.  Also note, no database is being used - this is simply a get request on an external API.

Thanks in advance.

```
collect($results);
$outputs = $results->chunk(20)[$request->get('offset')];
dd($outputs);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$results` is still an array. You are not setting the new Collection you are creating to a variable: `collect($results)`. This does not change `$results`. So you are calling `chunk` on the array, `$results`. Call `chunk` on the Collection instead:

```
$collection = collect($results);
$outputs = $collection->chunk(20)...;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  But aren't I already calling `chunk` on the collection? `$collection->chunk(20)` where `$results` is the collection?

Comment: its not a Collection, reread what I wrote ... `collect($results)` does not change `$results`. `$results` is the array you passed to `collect`, the new Collection is returned from the call to `collect`

Comment: sorry may you please demonstrate? I'm a little confused :)

Comment: I did demonstrate ... that is what the answer is; read the answer

Comment: oh wait I see it, sorry for my brain fog.  I've been stuck on this for a while!  Let me give that a try.

Comment: no worries, just look at the code in the answer and you will get it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241933/discussion-between-sp92-and-lagbox).